# find positive calendarDurations in matlab

Tags: matlab

AIM: 
I need to synchronize the animation of two plots in Matlab.

PROBLEM:
The data of the two plots has been acquired with a variable sample rate.

SOLUTION:
I converted the time-stamps of the two datasets in duration objects (relative to the beginning of the streaming). 
Now I want to plot the two datasets in a for loop.
For each loop, I want to show the datasets samples whose durations are within the elapsed time.

QUESTION: 
How do I determine if the duration of a specific sample already happened or not?

CODE EXAMPLE:
here I simulate and sort 10 random durations (d1), and 1 random elapsed time (et). I want to find which durations are past the elapsed time.

`

```
% simulate elapsed time
et = calendarDuration(round(rand(1,6)*10));

% simulate data for plot 1 
data_for_plot1 = rand(10,1);

% simulate durations for the samples in plot1
d1 = calendarDuration(sortrows(round(rand(10,6)*10))); 

% find index of durations which are before the elapsed time
is_past = (d1-et)>0;

% plot the data
plot(data_for_plot1(is_past))
```

`

ERROR MESSAGE

`is_past = (d1-et)>0;`

Undefined operator '>' for input arguments of type 'calendarDuration'.

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTIONS:
It's my first time with duration and date objects, and I am hating every bit of it. If you have alternative solutions I would love to hear them. 
Mind that the timestamps of data1 come as strings ('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') and the timestamps of data2 come as double (eg: 42.525, 42 s and 525 ms).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`split`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) function for this purpose.

Use  `is_past = split((d1-et),'time')> 0;` instead of `is_past = (d1-et)>0;`